# SPI sensor wireless transmission using nrf24l01+ but without microcontroller

Tags: spi, wireless, nrf24l01

I have a tiny sensor which has SPI signal. The sensor has only two lines (other than power and ground) and it takes clcok signal from a board and sends the SPI signal back to the board. I want to take this sensor away from the board and send the signal wirelessly. The whole system doesnt need arduino as the signal is already an SPI. I just need to transmit it.[image: the current and proposed system is illustrated in the picture attached]

Answer (score 1):

> I just need to transmit it.

Not possible with "just" 2 nrf24L01 chips, there is more to RF communication and protocols. The sensor does not know how to talk to an NRF24L01, and the SPI protocol is vastly different on the arduino side.

What you could do is use more modern modules based on NRF51xxx or NRF52xxx chips, which have *both* radio and µC included.

You might be able to replace the arduino MCU fully with the one in the NRF module on the "motherboard" side, but it can also work as an SPI slave.

On the osther side, the module needs to know how to talk to the sensor.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Is there any possibility that i could take the signal and transmit it over short distance without using any form of microcontroller and programming?

Comment: no, there is not. No matter what, if you need to read from an SPI sensor and transmit it to another device wirelessly, a microcontroller is the cheapest and easiest way to do it *by far*. This is basically a purpose-built microcontroller application